# Is it possible to print multiple lines on snackbar ? Is there is word limit?

Tags: android, snackbar

I know Snackbar is just to show a short message.But for one of my it's asking me to print multiple line.Is that possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705607/android-multiline-snackbar/31429069#31429069

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By Default it  only support max of 2 lines. if you want to increase it you can change the attribute of setting Max line of snackBar textview by below way.

```
View yourSnackBarView = snackbar.getView(); //get your snackbar view
TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text); //Get reference of snackbar textview
textView.setMaxLines(3); // Change your max lines
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible. You can try to put "\n" in between your lines. (Although, It may not look nice to put many lines on a snackbar)

Example:

```
Snackbar.make(view, "This is first line\nThis is second line", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```