# Clip all the data except a certain data from server response to use in app

Tags: android, server-response

I am getting a response from the server as below,

```
<p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px;"> <strong>XXX Pvt Ltd. has been used 3 times.The contact information for XXX can only be viewed -4 more times on App until it expires. Please urgently verify the information.</strong></p>
```

Here I would need the integer value -4 if it is negative or 4 if it is positive. In case it is negative I would like to get it with the negative sign.

Is there any way to clip all the text values and just get a part of the response from the server in android?

I actually need the count of times we can see the info above in my app.

I tried researching and gone through some links as,

[Remove all occurrences of \ from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939925/remove-all-occurrences-of-from-string)

[How to replace the characher `\n` as a new line in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417581/how-to-replace-the-characher-n-as-a-new-line-in-android)

[How to strip or escape html tags in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502759/how-to-strip-or-escape-html-tags-in-android)

However, none of this could actually help me in achieving what I want.

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked at Regular Expressions? 
If this is the string you receive you could simply apply a regEx on that to filter out the needed informations.

Comment: @Nico Can u please advise what regex shall I use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last digit from a `String` using this:

```
String s = "";
String str = "<p style=\\\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px;\\\"> <strong> This is the information you need 5 times you can see.</strong></p>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    s = m.group();
}
int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

`number` is the number from your html string.

See: https://regex101.com/r/jAFJiL/1

Edit, multiple numbers:

Here is a small ugly piece of code I wrote for you. This gets all numbers from a `String` and removes the first one. (The `18px` from your input):

```
String str = "<p style=\"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px;\"> <strong>XXX Pvt Ltd. has been used 3 times.The contact information for XXX can only be viewed 4 more times on App until it expires. Please urgently verify the information.</strong></p>";
boolean previousWasDigit = false;

ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
String number = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        if (previousWasDigit) {
            number += c;
        } else {
            number = Character.toString(c);
        }
        previousWasDigit = true;
    } else {
       if (previousWasDigit) {
           numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(number));
       }
       previousWasDigit = false;
    }
}
numbers.remove(0); // we remove the first digit (18) here
// numbers contains the digits of your string
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, However, I am getting "illegal escape character in string literal" error here. ANy idea why would that happen?

Comment: Hey thanks the pattern seems fine but I got another error in the line result = m.group(); It says Incompatble types. Required Boolean Found String.

Comment: Incompatble types. Required Boolean. Found String. result is string but it requires boolean

Comment: There is one more issue I am facing here... in case I am having 2 numbers at 2 different places.. the result is appending both the numbers. Please see the edited question

Comment: What do you mean? You have `18` and `5` in your string, and my regex only gets `5`.

Comment: It working but sometimes it's appending the numbers. Like In case I have the string as in my question I get 34.

Comment: Hey I am facing an issue again here.. in case I am having my number in negative like -7, the regex is only returning 7. Is there any way I can get the minus as well when it's in the negative?